# FOSUserBundle how to extend handler correctly

Tags: symfony, handler, fosuserbundle

It throws this error:

> Unrecognized option "handler" under "fos_user.registration.form"

And the files are:

```
    //services.yml
    app.form.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\AccomodationFrontSignUpType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }

    app.form.handler.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler
        arguments: ["@fos_user.registration.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager", "@fos_user.mailer", "@fos_user.util.token_generator"]
        scope: request
        public: false

//config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: AppBundle\Entity\Group
    service:
        mailer: swiftmailer.mailer.strato
    from_email:
            address:        webmyhomepage@strato.com
            sender_name:    myHomepage
    registration:
        form:
            handler: app.form.handler.registration
            type: app_user_registration
        confirmation:
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
            enabled: true
```

Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that there is an invalid parameter in your config. The key handler in your config

```
-> handler: app.form.handler.registration
```

if you take a look inside the fos user bundle DependencyInjection folder, Configuration.php file, that option does not exist. so its invalid :).
There you can see witch options are available. In my current version of this bundle i have this options available under form: type, name, validation_groups.

Also you can see the default configuration for a bundle with:

```
php app/console debug:config FOSUserBundle
```

Comment: yeah, that is just the question... why does it throw 'handler' as invalid

Comment: the handler its not invalid, the option key is

Comment: great, I didn't know the version had changed... thanks!